# How to Query the multiple values of same coulmn in sqlserver 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

MY Table like this:

```
id  Tag                platform
1  #class1,#class2      CS
2  #class1              PS
3  #class2              CS
```

if i pass "'#class1'" as parameter to SP getting only one record that is 2nd record.But need to 1st and 2nd records because #class1 contains in both 1,2 rows.Please tell me how to write this.I am using IN statement as of now.By using getting only record.

MY SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Get]-- 1,"'#class1,#class2'"
@Appid INT,
@TagList NVARCHAR (MAX)
AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SELECT @TagList = '%' + RTRIM(LTRIM(@TagList)) + '%';
  declare @tags varchar(MAX)
    set @tags = @TagList
    create table #t (tag varchar(MAX))
    set @tags = 'insert #t select ' + replace(@tags, ',', ' union select ')
    exec(@tags)
Select 
    id FROM dbo.List WHERE ((appid=@Appid)) AND ((Tags LIKE(select tag from #t)
END
```

How to modify please tell me...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use LIKE operator in your stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindTag @TagName char(50)
AS
    SELECT @TagName = '%' + TRIM(@TagName) + '%';

    SELECT Tag 
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE Tag LIKE @TagName;

GO
```

Comment: How Add % % to string while passing it into SP?as of now i am  passing  string as "'#class1,#class2'"like that how to add % to that string in sqlserver.....

Comment: Please see my Modified SP.How to change to get 1,2 ,3 rows records if i pass Tag as "'#class1','#class2'"

Comment: Looks like proper Transact SQL will be to use RTRIM(LTRIM(@TagName)) instead.

Comment: incorrect syntax while passing parameter as "'#class1','#class2'".Can you please check my moodified SP......How to pass parameters to that?

Comment: It sounds like the syntax issue is caused by un-escaped single quotation marks ('). In that case, replacing "'" with ` (back quote character) should help: replace(@tags, `'`, ''). Unfortunately I don't have a SQL Server instance available at the moment to try it on.

Comment: Note: I can't get the above comment to render ` (back quote character) correctly in replace function.

Comment: Not Getting @Blues.Need to pass like Taglist="'%class1%','%class2%'"  to SP.Can Check my SP Once.What was wrong?if i pass #class1 as Taglist parameter need to get 1,2 rows records.because class1 is there in 1,2 rows.please help me out i'm confusing....